# Event for showing map marker content in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have a google map integration in my ionic app. I want my marker on map appear whenever map appears however it depends on 'click' event. I have changed into 'idle' however, it doesn't even show the content of marker.

Question: Into what shall I change 'click'?

```
function getMap(lat, lon, content) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        //Wait until the map is loaded
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function () {

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: latLng
          });

          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
          });
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete  `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {})` and leave  `infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);` alone